# Traefik fails to obtain letsencrypt certificate for internal domain: DNS update failed: dns: bad signature

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, traefik

my goal is to be able to obtain certificates for "internal" domains using traefik. With "internal", I mean there is no public A record. For this reason, I won't be able to use the http challenge offered by letsencrypt. Therefore, I am trying to configure traefik's certresolver to use the dns01 challenge.

What I have achieved so far:

- bind is configured to accept dynamic updates using the key `traefik-key`
- adding and removing TXT records using the key mentioned above with `nsupdate` works

What does not work:

- traefik is not able to successfully request a certificate:`[WARN] [sub.example.com] acme: cleaning up failed: rfc2136: failed to remove: DNS update failed: dns: bad signature "`

Enabling the dns01 challenge should be easy:

```
certificatesResolvers:
  myresolver:
    acme:
      email: acme@example.com
      storage: /etc/traefik/acme.json
      #caServer: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: rfc2136
```

Those environment variables are set within the traefik container (key is obviously not the real one):

```
RFC2136_NAMESERVER=ns1.example.com
RFC2136_TSIG_ALGORITHM=hmac-sha256.
RFC2136_TSIG_KEY=traefik-key
RFC2136_TSIG_SECRET=GWyS8tTnqO2idhxXnC8Vtc+tY5cMaKA/9RLpSlMeqKM=
```

What is the matter with my configuration? Do I maybe still need an A record?
Bad signature sounds like an issue with TSIG, but I can't find it and as already mentioned, the key/secret combination works with `nsupdate`.

Not to mention, there isn't *any* entry in the log of the nameserver about a successful/failed attempt to add a TXT record. Only when I omit the TSIG configuration, it returns the status `NOTIMP` instead of the message above.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well no... As I already mentioned: that's *not* my real key ;)

Comment: Never mind then =)

Answer (score 0):

Ah forget it.

> Not to mention, there isn't any entry in the log of the nameserver about a successful/failed attempt to add a TXT record.

Was the hint I didn't get yesterday. Once upon a time (long ago), I wasn't too happy with browsers using their own DNS. So, I redirected every lookup to my own DNS. The same happened to the acme script, trying to create the TXT record.

Without this redirection it works as a charm.